# Component not updating on pop()

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm using `Redux` for state management.  I haven't ran into many problems with it until I've moved my Navigation stack to use `pop()` appropriately. The issue is actually quite simple:

1. Route A displays some data and moves the user to Route B.
2. On Route B the user changed the data displayed on Route A.
3. The user then hits the back button, and pops to Route A.
4. Route A has not updated, even though the redux state has been.
5. I must then exit Route A, and return to Route A through a .push() in order for the changes to take affect.

I'm trying to find a solution for this, but cannot. Is there any way to determine when a component enters the front screen again? As `render()` isn't called again, because it doesn't receive any new props while in the background, so there' no reason for it to be called.

Answer (score 0):

Basically on `pop()`, the component is already mounted so it won't re-render anything. I really hope they eventually add an `onFocus()` method to components but the way I handled it is by passing the method that updates component A to component B when you push, then invoke it when you're popping so component A will re-render with the new information.

Comment: This really isn't viable since what I'm doing is a messenger, and I'm popping back to all the different message threads. The state is updated through a asynchronous response from the REST API when a message is sent.

Comment: Depends how you have you're messenger set up. You're posting the message to the server and on success you pop, correct? So won't a fresh get request when you pop grab the updated list data? I have something similar set up and it works without issues.

Comment: No. I can post several messages to the server. The state is updated when a REST request is completed. But the user can receive new messages and send new messages without popping. I just tried hacking the state of the thread component.  `setState(...); Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the Messenger component`  So I couldn't update the state on my `Threads` component by passing an update hack through to the Messenger.

Comment: I don't issue get requests to obtain all my messages; I have a notification server that tells me when I need to get a single resource from the server. This is automatic and is completely independent of any component. It updates the store in the background without any user interaction, regarldess of the active component. So a server will send a packet saying "Hey, GET message/17" and the app will automatically get that resource and update the redux state.

Comment: Do you have a redux action to update your threads component with the new messages from your store?